# Resolving the integral for the amplitude of the excited mode in a plucked string

Tags: integration

So I came at the final step to find an expression for the excited mode of a plucked string and here is my result:

\begin{equation}
    A_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lf(x)sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx = \frac{2}{L}\left[\int_0^{pL}\frac{A_0}{pL}xsin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx + \int_{pL}^L\frac{A_0}{L(1-p)}(L-x)sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    = \frac{2}{L}\left[\frac{A_0}{pL}\int_0^{pL}xsin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx + \frac{A_0}{L(1-p)}\int_{pL}^L(L-x)sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    = \frac{2A_0}{L^2}\left[\frac{1}{p}\int_0^{pL}xsin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx + \frac{1}{(1-p)}\int_{pL}^L(L-x)sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    = \frac{2A_0}{L^2}\left[\frac{1}{p}\left[\frac{L^2}{n^2\pi^2}(sin(n\pi p) - n\pi pcos(n\pi p)\right] + \frac{1}{1-p}\left[\frac{l^2}{{\pi}^2n^2}\left(\sin\left({\pi}np\right)+\left({\pi}n-{\pi}np\right)\cos\left({\pi}np\right)\right)\right]\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    A_n = sin(n\pi p)\left[\frac{2A_0}{pn^2\pi^2} + \frac{L^2}{(1-p)n^2\pi^2}\right] + cos(n\pi p)\left[\frac{L^2}{(1-p)n\pi} - \frac{2A_0}{n\pi} - \frac{L^2p}{(1-p)n\pi}\right]
\end{equation}

But I'm supposed to get this:

\begin{equation}
    A_n = \frac{4A_0}{pn^2\pi^2}\sin{(pn\pi)}
\end{equation}

Where $A_n$ is the amplitude of the excited modes. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdtJB.png) is the link for the picture of the situation (the plucked string) if it can help you. What did I do wrong or can I use some relations to get to the supposed result?

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors. One is in the formula you’re supposedly supposed to get: This is missing a factor $1-p$ in the denominator. (The original integral is symmetric with respect to $p\to1-p$ for odd $n$, so the result must be, too.)

The other error is in the last line of your calculations. Everything up to that looks good, but then you got lots of factors wrong. In fact the factors of $A_0$ and $L^2$ are the same in all these terms; the factors $L^2$ in the numerators and the denominator cancel and only $A_0$ remains (as it must; the result is proportional to $A_0$, since $f$ is). The coefficients of the cosine cancel and the coefficients of the sine can be combined by expanding them to a common denominator $p(1-p)$.

Comment: I don't understand the second error that you are describing and why $A_0$ and $L^2$ are the same. Is the last line of my calculation the one where I give my final answer for $A_n$ or the one before that? I see indeed that the $L^2$ cancel, my bad.

Comment: @MathieuGirard: The one where you give your final answer for $A_n$. There may be a misunderstanding – I didn't say that $A_0$ and $L^2$ are the same, but that these factors are the same in all the terms; I meant that each term has the same factors of $A_0$ (once in the numerator) and of $L^2$ (once in the overall denominator, once in the individual numerators, and thus cancelled).

Comment: Ah yes i see now, I'll do again this part and I'll tell you if I get it! Also, just to be sure, you're saying that the final answer should be $A_n = \frac{4A_0}{p(1-p)n^2\pi^2}sin(n\pi p)$?

Comment: @MathieuGirard: I think so. I didn't work it all out in detail myself, but your calculation seemed correct except for the last line, and it yields $p(1-p)$ in the denominator and that has the right answer and the "supposed" answer doesn't, so it's likely to be correct.

Comment: Yes I got it! Except I have a 2 in the numerator instead of a 4 but I think it is indeed a 2.

Comment: @MathieuGirard: Sorry, that was meant to read "and that has the right symmetry" instead of "and that has the right answer" (too late to edit now).